# How did the letter Z come to be associated with sleeping/snoring?

Tags: etymology, onomatopoeia

In cartoons and comics it's not uncommon to see a series of Z's to indicate that a person is in deep slumber, such as in the following political cartoon.

[image: Cartoon of a man sleeping in front of a television set]

*(source: Berkeley Daily Planet)*

How and when did the letter Z come to be associated with sleeping?

Comment: Seemzz perhaps sleep should be represented as "Oooo" rather than "Zzzz". O's as balloons of dreams.

Comment: Also, maybe, "How many Zs in the onomatopoeia for sleeping/ snoring?" Any standards/ style guides?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

"How and when did the letter Z become to be associated with sleeping?"

First of all, zzzz (or z-z-z-z) is sound of snoring, from at least 1918. (Sometimes "a tiny saw cutting through a log" [1948] would be used, and both the snore and saw would make the same z-z-z-z sound.) Over time, this became associated with sleep in general, but most comic reference books (e.g. 2006's *KA-BOOM! A Dictionary of Comic Book Words, Symbols & Onomatopoeia*, 2008's *Comic books: how the industry works*) still mainly associate it with snoring.

See also [Why Does ZZZ mean sleep?](http://www.knowswhy.com/why-does-zzz-mean-sleep/) for another theory:

> The reason zzz came into being is that the
>   comic strip artists just couldn’t
>   represent sleeping with much. ... As
>   the sounds made while sleeping are
>   quite difficult to represent with
>   letters, the artists chose zzz,
>   because it best represents the sound
>   ... In fact it has made itself into
>   its own meaning - it no longer needs
>   explanation and is generally accepted
>   world wide as a representation of
>   sleeping. The reason it even became
>   what it now is, is almost lost, such
>   as the meaning of the wrong end of the
>   stick. I’ll let you figure that one
>   out.

The earliest references I found connect zzzz with snoring, including an explanation that says snoring is indicated by zzzz.

[American Dialect Society's Dialect notes, Volume 5](http://books.google.com/books?ei=FcveTfCbCs6q8QOP8qGbCg&ct=result&id=lxwOAAAAIAAJ&dq=zzz%20snore%20comic&q=zzz%20#search_anchor), 1918:

> z-z-z (buzzing, or snoring)

[*Boys' Life*](http://books.google.com/books?id=q8YNfaVVh5MC&pg=PA26&dq=zzzzzzzz%20snore&hl=en&ei=q3feTYLnGoucOrDmhIQK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=sheet%20music&f=false) in Jan 1919, and The Boy Scouts' year book also in 1919:

> **Z-z-z-z-z-z-z-z-z**
>
> Tenderfoot: "Do you know the scientific name for snoring?"
>
> Eagle Scout: "Uh, no."
>
> Tenderfoot: "Sheet Music."

[*Life* magazine, Volume 79](http://books.google.com/books?id=7RAaAAAAMAAJ&q=indicated+by+ZZZZZZZ.&dq=indicated+by+ZZZZZZZ.&hl=en&ei=Z3feTb-aHcyaOpbOsfYJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA) in 1922:

> Snoring is indicated by "**ZZZZZZZ**."
>   which often is supplemented by a.
>   picture like this: Profanity may be
>   conveyed by a series of punctuation
>   marks and hieroglyphics, such as :
>   ?;!f

[*Boys' Life*](http://books.google.com/books?id=VrybVE0S5QIC&pg=PA44&dq=zzzz%20snored&hl=en&ei=Y3TeTZuyNYyVOtGphYMK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=zzzz&f=false) in Oct 1927, recycling their jokes:

> **Z-Z-Z-Z**
>
> Tenderfoot: "Do you know the scientific name for snoring?"
>
> Eagle Scout: "Why, no."
>
> Tenderfoot: "Sheet music."

[*Contact point*](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=zzzzz&btnG=Search%20Books#sclient=psy&hl=en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1900,cd_max:12/31/1930&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=zzzzzz%20snore%20&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=eb9d385e1d7925bd&biw=1920&bih=1061) by the University of the Pacific, School of Dentistry in 1927:

> **ZZZZZZ** (snoring)— Heard during
>   lecture. 2. The Scolenius Medius. the
>   largest and longest of the three
>   Scoleni. arises from the posterior
>   tubercle of the transverse processes
>   of the lower six cervical vertebrae,
>   and descending along, ...

[Boys Life](http://books.google.com/books?id=3yyRrhS776UC&pg=PA48&dq=zzzzzzz%20snore&hl=en&ei=dnXeTfvwA4qSOtDyjIUL&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%20zzzzzzz%20&f=false) yet again in Nov 1928, this time with an illustration:

> **zzzzzzz**
>
> One: What is snoring?
>
> Two: Sheet music.

[Illinois education, Volume 42](http://books.google.com/books?id=uA3lAAAAMAAJ&q=zzzzzzz%20sleep&dq=zzzzzzz%20sleep&hl=en&ei=n3PeTbKLB8aBOsrPnfYJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA) in 1953:

> So saying, Tooten hitched his falling
>   socks, yawned, shut the door on his
>   intellectual rescrvdir now devoid of
>   any running comment, and went back to
>   sleep.
>
> Calico called her first grade
>   to order. "**Zzzzzzz**," quavered she, "is
>   the sound of the bee, the one with
>   wings, but stands for Z. Congusing,
>   isn't it?"
>
> **Zzzzzzz** snored president
>   Timothy.

[*Instructor*, Volume 67](http://books.google.com/books?id=kHtQAAAAYAAJ&q=zzzzzz%20sleep&dq=zzzzzz%20sleep&hl=en&ei=SHPeTZPuBoPrOfPZnP8J&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA) in 1957:

> A little girl who had learned her
>   alphabet began by Awakening and
>   followed the alphabet all through the
>   day, each letter representing many
>   things, until she went to sleep,
>   **Zzzzzz**.

[*My name is--: a game of letters and their sounds*](http://books.google.com/books?ei=b3LeTZLLKoGhOqnw9OUJ&ct=result&id=0MsEAQAAIAAJ&dq=zzzzz%20sleep&q=zzzzz#search_anchor) by Lois Baker Muehl in 1959:

> This may sound crazy, but even in the
>   breeze the zigzag cages will seem
>   cozy. They will all be the right kind
>   and size. And at night I will play a
>   zither to help all the animals go to
>   sleep and snooze, **Zzzzz**

---

Edit: Another [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_balloon#The_big_Z):

> **The big Z**
>
> It is a convention in American comics
>   that the sound of a snore can be
>   reduced to a single letter Z. Thus a
>   speech bubble with this letter
>   standing all alone (again, drawn by
>   hand rather than a font type) means
>   the character is sleeping in most
>   humorous comics. This can be seen, for
>   instance, in Charles Schulz's *Peanuts*
>   comic strips.
>
> **Being such a long-established device,
>   the Z-bubble does not even imply that
>   the character is snoring anymore, but
>   just sleeping.** Jim Davis has based
>   some jokes starring Garfield upon this
>   technique; for example, in one strip,
>   Garfield is unable to sleep because
>   his Z-bubble is pointing in the wrong
>   direction. When he grabs the bubble's
>   tail to make it point at himself, he
>   falls asleep.
>
> Originally, the resemblance between
>   the 'z' sound and that of a snore
>   seemed exclusive to the English
>   language, but the spread of American
>   comics has made it a frequent feature
>   in other countries. An exception to
>   this is in Japanese manga, where the
>   usual symbol for sleep is a large
>   bubble coming out of the character's
>   nose.

Comment: How is the letter pronounced in this usage? /zɛd/ or /ziː/? Also, could anyone show me how a common snoring sound under English environment is (maybe in IPA form)? As a non-native-english speaker I still cannot understand the onomatopoeic relationship.

Comment: Closer to /ziː/, imagine a long zurrrrrrh sound rather than repeated zee zee or zed zed letters

Comment: Thx. Well that feels better but still far from what I imagine a snoring sound is. I'll ask if someone near can perform for me.

Answer (score 9):

I have just discovered this question and am surprised that more reference has not been made to the word ***snooze***. There is a passing reference in the accepted answer but, on checking, this word dates back to 1789 and is described as 'a cant word, echoic of a snore.' Cartoons through the years seem to have extended ***snooze*** or borrowed the latter ***zzz*** sound which, by default, has become its representation. My theory, anyway!

Answer (score 6):

Someone came close to the correct answer, but failed to put 2 and 2 together.  The letter Z represents the motion of someone sawing wood with a hand saw, which sounds close to the sound of someone snoring.  Originally someone "sawing wood" was the description given to the sound when snoring, often accompanied by an image of sawing wood or a hand motion (in the Z formation) of someone sawing wood.  Later it was condensed and simplified just by using the letter Z or a series of Z's (ZZZZZZ = Sawing Wood = Snoring Sound)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z) :

> Zzz or zzzz is used in writing to represent the act of sleeping. It is used because human snoring often sounds like the pronunciation of the letter.

Comment: i.e. an [onomatopoeia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) for snoring

Comment: Zzzzz seems to more closely match the sound of a buzzing fly, IMO, but I get it. Do you have any insight on to when it was first used?

Comment: @Scott Mitchell: [The only thing](http://ask.yahoo.com/20060317.html) I've found after 30 minutes.

Comment: Yes, but seemingly only in modern American cultures.  Japanese culture (see manga) portrays sleeping with a bubble protruding from a nostril.

Comment: I'm not convinced this very pat explanation is sufficient. The person who added [citation needed] to the Wikipedia article agrees. I've never heard any snoring that sounds like [zzzz]. The sound requires conscious tongue positioning and vocal cord vibration to produce, which is difficult to do while unconscious.

Comment: @Nohat: You've never heard?? I don't know snoring sounds different in different cultures and countries, but snoring sounds really something like "zzzz" here. The point is, the sound is not exactly like pronouncing "z" with tongue positioning and vocal cord vibration that needs to wake up, but the nearest sound to it is "z".

Comment: I didn't think zzz sounds much like snoring, but check my answer -- the earliest references are for snoring, and another Wikipedia article says it's such a long-standing device that it now also means sleeping.

Comment: @Boob I get that this is an answer that might be a correct explanation, but there is no evidence at all whatsoever that it is. **[[citation needed]]**

Comment: I have never heard a snoring person with anything close to a Z, and I have lived with some EPIC snorers. Epic I tell you. It is more like "snnCHHhkkkk,,,phsawwww" :)

Comment: @horatio: Could you please check again? =/  ..

Answer (score -3):

Z looks like (also sounds like) electrical wave, and people send out brain waves when they are sleeping.

See: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_wave)

Comment: i didn't downvote, but for what it's worth, people "send out" brain waves every moment they're alive.

Comment: @Matthew: the brain wave is particular important when people refers to sleep.

Comment: It's a matter of perspective, I guess. Of the dozen or so clinical uses in the Wikipedia article you linked to, sleep isn't even listed. But it's fine, I don't need to convince you, I just wanted to point out that "people send out brain waves when they are sleeping" makes it sound like EEG activity only happens when you're sleeping; the fact is that it happens all the time.

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, EEG happens all the time. But when awake, people send out brain waves, doing their work, study and play. But when sleep, people do only send out brain waves.

Comment: I think what he's saying is that brain electrical activity is pretty much the only activity during sleep. Hence the electrical symbol (lightning strike) which resembles and is substituted with is Z. Like dreams happening due to (electrical) brain activity.

Comment: Yeh.. When I first saw Zzzz in cartoons I was a child, with no english knowledge. It's the shape rather then the sound, that I could associate it with sleep. I think it's the shape took the most important place to make Zzzz be world-wide accepted.