# What is the origin of using the letters 'ZZZ' to symbolize a person sleeping?

Tags: etymology, slang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did the letter Z become to be associated with sleeping/snoring?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/how-did-the-letter-z-become-to-be-associated-with-sleeping-snoring)

In old cartoons and even now in other such media, often the letters 'zzz' are used to indicate that a person is sleeping. What is the origin of this? It seems that the sound that someone makes when they are snoring isn't zzz at all, but rather, as a friend put it, a series of rolling rrrrrs.

Comment: It seems that the general consensus is that it was chosen to represent the sound of snoring. The answer to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/how-did-the-letter-z-become-to-be-associated-with-sleeping-snoring) should also answer yours.